# Mongoose Return Error Code 11000 duplicate index

Tags: javascript, web, mongoose, duplicates, backend

i am using mongoose as database for my project, now i am struggling with add data to multiple collections and this is my route

`router.post('/',add_new_user_to_specific_collection,add_new_user_to_collection_User);`

this is code of middleware `add_new_user_to_specific_collection`:

```
exports.add_new_user_to_specific_collection = (req, res, next) => {
  const {role, fullname, code} = req.body;

  const generator = new AvatarGenerator(); // it generate random image, no worry
  const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(code.toString(), 10);
  console.log(hashedPassword);
  const newUserData = {
    password: hashedPassword,
    profileImage: generator.generateRandomAvatar(),
  };

  if (role === 'consultant') {
    var newConsultant = new Consultant({
      fullname,
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      fullname,
      code,
      vnumail: code.trim() + '@vnu.edu.vn',
      ...newUserData,
    });

    newConsultant
      .save()
      .then((doc) => {
        console.log('New User as Consultant was added');
        req.newUserData = newUserData;
        next();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({err});
      });
  }
};
```

and this is for `add_new_user_to_collection_User`:

```
exports.add_new_user_to_collection_User = (req, res, next) => {
  const {role, fullname, code} = req.body;

  const newUser = new User({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    role,
    fullname,
    code,
    vnumail: code.trim() + '@vnu.edu.vn',
    ...req.newUserData,
  });

  newUser
    .save()
    .then((doc) => {
      console.log('New User added to collection User');
      return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'User added',
        doc,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json(error);
    });
};
```

the input data is totally validated,

[image: fda]

and at the first try, it worked perfectly, but when it comes to the second times, i got this Error:

```
{
  "err.driver": true,
  "err.name": "MongoError",
  "err.index": 0,
  "err.code": 11000,
  "err.keyPattern.email": 1,
  "err.keyValue.email": null
}
```

i have researched for a while and look like email was duplicated but i don't assign any `email` property from the body of frontend

**UPDATE: THIS IS MY SCHEMA**

`userSchema`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  code: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  fullname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  activated: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  vnumail: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/,
  },
  profileImage: {
    type: String,
    default:
      'https://kittyinpink.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/facebook-default-photo-male_1-1.jpg',
  },

  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: [
      'consultant',
      'parent',
      'student',
      'specialist',
      'uet-leader',
      'student-affair-leader',
      'academic-leader',
    ],
    default: 'student',
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

`consultantSchema`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const consultantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  fullname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  code: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['Male', 'Female', 'No Record'],
    default: 'No Record',
  },
  birthday: {
    type: Date,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/,
  },
  vnumail: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/,
  },
  profileImage: {
    type: String,
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
  },
  academicRank: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['master', 'phd', 'professor'],
    default: 'master',
  },
  specialize: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const Consultant = mongoose.model('Consultant', consultantSchema);

module.exports = Consultant;
```

thank you so much for help me out, it means a lot to me, i hope you have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested on my local but from the code it seems that you're getting an error because you never assign any value to `email` field for `Consultant` while it (almost) must be assigned.

To be more precise, the problem (most likely where the fix is needed) is here:

```
var newConsultant = new Consultant({
  fullname,
  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  fullname,
  code,
  vnumail: code.trim() + '@vnu.edu.vn',
  ...newUserData,
});
```

You create on object with various properties (by the way, you duplicated `fullname` twice) but the `email` is not set. And if it is not set, you can only save to database once because `null` value is still acceptable but with the second insertion, you would get an error because `null` is no longer a unique value.

To solve this, you need to assign a unique value to `email` field, for example:

```
var newConsultant = new Consultant({
  fullname,
  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  email: <some_random_and_unique_email>,
  code,
  vnumail: code.trim() + '@vnu.edu.vn',
  ...newUserData,
});
```

If `email` is not necessarily required/unique, then you would need to update `consultantSchema` instead and remove unique: true`for`email` field.

Comment: thank you so much, i just have followed what you told me and it worked, but i can not get it why, i don't assign property "email" in the schema User but i have to assign one and it works magically

Comment: @TamDo There is no magic here. `User` schema does not contain `email` field so it works without assigning one. In fact, without `email` field in schema, Mongoose would not even save this field to database, even if you assign a value in code.

Comment: but it will cause confusing to me because i assigned a property that does not exist in the schema to make it works :(

Comment: You can append to object with any field and it would seem to be working but at the Mongoose level (before save/update), it simply removes all fields that are not present in schema.